# asp.net core on linux with nginx routing doesn't work

Tags: linux, nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I've created an `ASP.NET Core MVC` application and deployed it into Linux server. When I go to sitename.com browser shows up the Home/Index page without any problem.

But when I try to go `sitename.com/Home/Index` or another controller like `sitename.com/Admin/Login` nginx throws a `404 Not Found` error. What should be the problem?

Here is my `Startup.cs/Configure` method.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Here is my website config from `sites-available` folder

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

   root /var/www/sitename.com;
   index index.html index.htm;

   server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
   }
```

and `nginx.conf`

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
    }

    http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }

    mail {

    }
```

Comment: Do these requests work if you send them to Kestrel directly?

Comment: When I run these lines on bash I'get the correct html responses. `curl http://localhost:5000/Home/Index` or `curl http://localhost:5000/Admin/Login` @AlexeyAndrushkevich

Comment: Then it worth sharing your `nginx.conf` file to see if it's configured properly.

Comment: I've added my config files to my question @AlexeyAndrushkevich

Comment: Did you try to remove `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`? For me this looks like it's testing if a certain url exists and if not return 404. But /Home/Index is a route, which do not map to an existing file but to controller action

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks a lot @Tseng

Comment: Hi, I stuck on the same 404 issue for a week. I removed  above statement but the issue still  persists. Could anyone please help me to resolve 404.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` as it's testing if a certain url exists on the file system and if not return 404.

But `/Home/Index` is a route, which do not map to an existing file but to controller action, hence you get the 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

To help someone searching on Google

I was getting 404, but I realized that ASP Net only accepts 1 server by name

Example **NOT POSSIBLE**:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    location /asp_app_ONE {
        proxy_pass     http://0.0.0.0:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /asp_app_TWO{
        proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Example OK:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name appONE.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass     http://0.0.0.0:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name appTWO.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass     http://0.0.0.0:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```